# Generate multiple lags through loops in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to generate 20 lags for a variable. 
To generate the first lag, I use the following statement:

```
data temp.data2;

    set temp.data1;
    by gvkey fyear; 
    lag1 =   ifn(gvkey=lag(gvkey) and fyear=lag(fyear)+1,lag(mv),.);
    lag2 =   ifn(gvkey=lag(gvkey) and fyear=lag(fyear)+1,lag(lag1),.); 
    etc.

run;
```

Don't want to repeat 20 times.  Is there a way to do this through a loop?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to maintain your own array of `mv` values and assign the lag values from that.  The array would be bubbled for each row processed and reset at the start of an `fyear` group.

Example:

```
data have; 
  do gvkey = 1 to 5;
    do fyear = 1 to 5;
      do day = 1 to ifn(fyear=3, 10, 30);
        mv = 366-day;
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by gvkey fyear;

  array mvs(20) _temporary_;
  array lags(20) lag1-lag20;

  if first.fyear then call missing(of mvs(*));

  * assign lags;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(lags);
    lags(_n_) = mvs(_n_);
  end;

  * bubble mvs;
  do _n_ = dim(lags) to 2 by -1;
    mvs(_n_) = mvs(_n_-1);
  end;
  mvs(1) = mv;
run;
```